# App force closes during displaying custom time picker

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, timepicker, forceclose

I am using [this](https://github.com/RedInput/DateTimePickerCompat) library to use custom time picker in my app. The relevant code from the TimePickerDialog class is as follows:

```
public static TimePickerDialog newInstance(OnTimeSetListener callback,
    int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourMode) {
TimePickerDialog ret = new TimePickerDialog();
ret.initialize(callback, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourMode);
return ret;
}
```

In my activity I have used this code to implement that:

```
com.android.datetimepicker.time.TimePickerDialog dialog = new        com.android.datetimepicker.time.TimePickerDialog();
dialog.newInstance((OnTimeSetListener) mTimeSetListener, getHour, getMinute, true);
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
dialog.show(fragmentManager, "timepicker");
```

But when I launch the app, I get a force close with following error:

`01-10 11:08:29.781    8727-8727/com.example.unplugged E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.unplugged.MainActivity$1 cannot be cast to com.android.datetimepicker.time.TimePickerDialog$OnTimeSetListener
            at com.example.unplugged.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:48)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4249)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17764)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5162)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:756)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:572)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Any suggestions?

Edit: The call back method:

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        setHour = hourOfDay;
        setMinute = minute;
    }
};
```

Comment: How you are initializing `mTimeSetListener` ?

Comment: what code is there on line 48? MainActivity.java:48 ? you must implement `TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener` to your activity. if  already there check your imports and see which `OnTimeSetListener` you have imported.

Comment: See my answer, it would do the job.

Comment: No need to cast just use `mTimeSetListener` instead of `(OnTimeSetListener) mTimeSetListener` as parameter in `dialog.newInstance`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be using `android.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener`

Change

```
dialog.newInstance((OnTimeSetListener) mTimeSetListener, getHour, getMinute, true);
```

to

```
dialog.newInstance(new com.android.datetimepicker.time.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        setHour = hourOfDay;
        setMinute = minute;
    }
}, getHour, getMinute, true);
```

Comment: You could simply update the import to `com.android.datetimepicker.time.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener`. That too would work.